# Stop building upstrea hudson job if downstream hudson jobs are running

Tags: hudson

I have setup hudson jobs in the following way:

Job A triggers Job B, C, D

Job A is pushing a new build every 6 hrs and then trigger Job B, C, D which will run test scripts on that build.

But sometimes, Job B, C, D takes more time, sometimes more than 6hrs. In this case of Job A pushes a new build, the tests results will be messed up with 2 builds.

So, I wanted to know if there is a way in Hudson to check if the downstream jobs are running, it Yes, then block the upstream  job till the downstream jobs complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your job A is probably configured to trigger the jobs B,C,D in the 'Post-build Actions'. It means that jobs B,C,D will be started after the job A completion.

You may try to trigger the B,C and D as an additional build step ( using 'Trigger/call builds on other projects' build step). You'll then have an option to wait till the downstream job is completed (just check the 'Block until the triggered projects finish their builds').

If you'd like to trigger all the B,C and D simultaneously just specify all of them in the same line ( the 'Projects to build' parameter of the 'Trigger/call builds on other projects' step). Otherwise you may add multiple such build steps for each job

Comment: Hi vladisld, I can see only "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" in my post-build section and I do not see any "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" option.

Comment: You need to make sure that the 'Parameterized Trigger Plugin' is installed on your system:[link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). Once installed you'll get the above 'build step' type available

Comment: I need to ask our Hudson admin to check if the plugin is installed and install if its not.

Comment: For anyone else who finds this question and can't find the option right away (like me) make sure you pay attention to the phrase "build step" in vladisld's comment. I was looking in post-build steps with the other project triggers.